# I am loading a tabbed content....But as default every tab content loads together...and once when i click on a tab...then it follows tabbed content way

Tags: javascript, tabs

Here is the javascript used, I need to stop loading everything on load

window.addEventListener('load', () => {

```
let portfolioContainer = select('.portfolio-container');
if (portfolioContainer) {
  let portfolioIsotope = new Isotope(portfolioContainer, {
    itemSelector: '.portfolio-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    
  });

  let portfolioFilters = select('#portfolio-flters li', true);

  on('click', '#portfolio-flters li', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    portfolioFilters.forEach(function(el) {
      el.classList.remove('filter-active');
    });
    this.classList.add('filter-active');

    portfolioIsotope.arrange({
      filter: this.getAttribute('data-filter')
    });
  }, true);
}
```

});

Library used
https://isotope.metafizzy.co

```
Here is the html content where its used...

<div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <ul id="portfolio-flters">
              <!-- <li data-filter="*" class="filter-active">All</li> -->
              <li data-filter=".filter-digital-graphics" class="filter-active">Digital Graphics</li>
              <li data-filter=".filter-card">Paintings</li>
              <!-- <li data-filter=".filter-web">Web</li> -->
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

<div class="row portfolio-container">

   
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-digital-graphics">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/digital_graphics/dg1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Digital Web Graphic</h4>
                <p>Digital Web Graphic</p>
              </div> 
              <div class="portfolio-links">
                <a href="assets/img/digital_graphics/dg1.jpg" data-gallery="portfolioGallery" class="portfolio-lightbox" title="Digital Web Graphic Design"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-card">
            <div class="portfolio-wrap">
              <img src="assets/img/paintings/1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              <div class="portfolio-info">
                <h4>Watercolor Painting</h4>
                <p>Painting</p>
              </div> 
              <div class="portfolio-links">
                <a href="assets/img/paintings/1.jpg" data-gallery="portfolioGallery" class="portfolio-lightbox" title="Watercolor Painting"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
enter code here
```

This is the htmlcss code used. When I load the page then both tab contents appear one below the other...but when I click on any one then it starts working properly....which is shown only the tabbed content at a time. Something is not working right on page load. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What library are you using? I see that you have ```select()``` and ```new Isotope``` and ```on()```

Comment: https://isotope.metafizzy.co

Comment: It would be better if you provide a HTML example.